# Display one content after another using CSS keyframes

Tags: html, css, css-animations, keyframe

I have the following `HMTL` and `CSS`:

```css
.parent{
 height: 10%;
 width: 100%;
 float: left;  
}
 
.content1{
 height: 100%;
 width: 20%;
 background-color: blue;
 float: left;
}
 
 .content2{
 height: 100%;
 width: 20%;
 background-color: red;
 float: left;
}
 
 .content3{ 
 height: 100%;
 width: 20%;
 background-color:yellow;
 float: left;
}
 
.content4{
 height: 100%;
 width: 20%; 
 background-color: green;
 float: left;
}
 
 .content5{
 height: 100%;
 width: 20%;
 background-color: orange;
 float: left;
}
 
 
 
.parent {
 animation-name: animation_01;
 animation-duration:5s;
 animation-iteration-count:1;
 animation-fill-mode: forwards;
 }


@keyframes animation_01 {
 
    0% {
    opacity: 0
    }
 
    20% {
    opacity: 1
    }
 
    40% {
    opacity: 0
    }
 
    60% {
    opacity: 1
    }
 
    80% {
    opacity: 0
    }
 
    100% {
    opacity: 1
    }
 
  }

}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
 <div class="content1">Here goes content1</div>
 <div class="content2">Here goes content2</div>
 <div class="content3">Here goes content3</div>
 <div class="content4">Here goes content4</div>
 <div class="content5">Here goes content5</div>
 </div>
```

This code itself works fine. 
You can also find it in the **JSfiddle** [here](https://jsfiddle.net/s6742tdf/).

---

My target now is to display `content1` to `content5` one after another. Therefore, I wanted to use the `opacity` function within the `animation` of the CSS. However, I could not yet figure out how I can use `opacity` for an individual content because right now the animation only runs for all five contents combined.

Do you know if its is possible to get this animation working within `@keyframes` or do I need javascript/jQuery like in the example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11775893/display-elements-one-after-another)?

Comment: So, do you want to first show content1, hide content1. then show content2, hide content2, and so on?

Comment: That is exactly what I am looking for.

Comment: Check @Itay Gal's answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to animate each div. You can use the same animation for all. For each div set `animation-delay`. Here is an example with the animation you defined in the question:

```css
.parent {
  height: 10%;
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
}

.parent div {
  animation-name: animation_01;
  animation-duration: 5s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  opacity: 0;
}

.content1 {
  height: 100%;
  width: 20%;
  background-color: blue;
  float: left;
}

.content2 {
  height: 100%;
  width: 20%;
  background-color: red;
  float: left;
  animation-delay: 1s;
}

.content3 {
  height: 100%;
  width: 20%;
  background-color: yellow;
  float: left;
  animation-delay: 2s;
}

.content4 {
  height: 100%;
  width: 20%;
  background-color: green;
  float: left;
  animation-delay: 3s;
}

.content5 {
  height: 100%;
  width: 20%;
  background-color: orange;
  float: left;
  animation-delay: 4s;
}

.parent {}

@keyframes animation_01 {
  0% {
    opacity: 0
  }
  20% {
    opacity: 1
  }
  40% {
    opacity: 0
  }
  60% {
    opacity: 1
  }
  80% {
    opacity: 0
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1
  }
}


}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="content1">Here goes content1</div>
  <div class="content2">Here goes content2</div>
  <div class="content3">Here goes content3</div>
  <div class="content4">Here goes content4</div>
  <div class="content5">Here goes content5</div>
</div>
```

or if you want each item to be shown for only 1 second for example:

```css
.parent {
  height: 10%;
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
}

.parent div {
  animation-name: animation_01;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  opacity: 0;
}

.content1 {
  height: 100%;
  width: 20%;
  background-color: blue;
  float: left;
}

.content2 {
  height: 100%;
  width: 20%;
  background-color: red;
  float: left;
  animation-delay: 1s;
}

.content3 {
  height: 100%;
  width: 20%;
  background-color: yellow;
  float: left;
  animation-delay: 2s;
}

.content4 {
  height: 100%;
  width: 20%;
  background-color: green;
  float: left;
  animation-delay: 3s;
}

.content5 {
  height: 100%;
  width: 20%;
  background-color: orange;
  float: left;
  animation-delay: 4s;
}

.parent {}

@keyframes animation_01 {
  0% {
    opacity: 0
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 1
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0
  }
}


}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="content1">Here goes content1</div>
  <div class="content2">Here goes content2</div>
  <div class="content3">Here goes content3</div>
  <div class="content4">Here goes content4</div>
  <div class="content5">Here goes content5</div>
</div>
```

**UPDATE**

To show them one on top of another set the parent `position:relative` and the children with `position: absolute`

```css
.parent {
  height: 10%;
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}

.parent div {
  animation-name: animation_01;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  opacity: 0;
}

.content1 {
  height: 100%;
  width: 20%;
  background-color: blue;
  position: absolute;
}

.content2 {
  height: 100%;
  width: 20%;
  background-color: red;
  animation-delay: 1s;
  position: absolute;
}

.content3 {
  height: 100%;
  width: 20%;
  background-color: yellow;
  animation-delay: 2s;
  position: absolute;
}

.content4 {
  height: 100%;
  width: 20%;
  background-color: green;
  animation-delay: 3s;
  position: absolute;
}

.content5 {
  height: 100%;
  width: 20%;
  background-color: orange;
  animation-delay: 4s;
}

.parent {}

@keyframes animation_01 {
  0% {
    opacity: 0
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 1
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0
  }
}


}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="content1">Here goes content1</div>
  <div class="content2">Here goes content2</div>
  <div class="content3">Here goes content3</div>
  <div class="content4">Here goes content4</div>
  <div class="content5">Here goes content5</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Looks good. Thanks for your help. Do you also have an idea how I can solve the issue if I want to show the contents one after another but instead of next to each other they are displayed on top of each other?

Comment: Not sure why, the code is inside the answer. Check out the third code snippet.

Comment: You might also have an idea for that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53376084/infinite-animation-of-contents-on-top-of-each-other-using-css-keyframes

Answer (score 1):

The idea is to add the animation onto the child element rather than the parent and add a `animation-delay` to delay the start time of each animation ( this is considerably easier when using sass )

```css
.parent{
 height: 10%;
 width: 100%;
 float: left;  
}
 
.content1{
 height: 100%;
 width: 20%;
 background-color: blue;
 float: left;

 
}
 
 .content2{
 height: 100%;
 width: 20%;
 background-color: red;
 float: left;
 animation-delay:.4s;
}
 
 .content3{ 
 height: 100%;
 width: 20%;
 background-color:yellow;
 float: left;
  animation-delay:.8s;
}
 
.content4{
 height: 100%;
 width: 20%; 
 background-color: green;
 float: left;
  animation-delay:1.2s;
}
 
 .content5{
 height: 100%;
 width: 20%;
 background-color: orange;
 float: left;
  animation-delay:1.6s;
}
 
 
 

 .parent div{
 animation-name: animation_01;
 animation-duration:5s;
 animation-iteration-count:1;
 animation-fill-mode: forwards;
 opacity:0;
}

@keyframes animation_01 {
 
    0% {
    opacity: 0;
    }
    100%{
    opacity:1;
  }

}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
 <div class="content1">Here goes content1</div>
 <div class="content2">Here goes content2</div>
 <div class="content3">Here goes content3</div>
 <div class="content4">Here goes content4</div>
 <div class="content5">Here goes content5</div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Nice but do you also have a solution if I want to first show content1, hide content1, then show content2, hide content2, and so on ... I have saved your current solution here https://jsfiddle.net/WebTiger/mp9cvg4t/1/ becasue I might need it for something else later.