# Infinite animation of contents on top of each other using CSS keyframes

Tags: html, css, css-animations, keyframe

I have the following `HTML` and `CSS` code:

```css
.parent{
 height: 10%;
 width: 100%;
 float: left;
 position: relative;
}
 
.content1{
 height: 100%;
 width: 20%;
 background-color: blue;
 float: left;
 position: absolute;
}
 
 .content2{
 height: 100%;
 width: 20%;
 background-color: red;
 float: left;
 animation-delay: 1s;
  position: absolute;
}
 
 .content3{ 
 height: 100%;
 width: 20%;
 background-color:yellow;
 float: left;
 animation-delay: 2s;
 position: absolute;
}
 
.content4{
 height: 100%;
 width: 20%; 
 background-color: green;
 float: left;
 animation-delay: 3s;
 position: absolute;
}
 
 .content5{
 height: 100%;
 width: 20%;
 background-color: orange;
 float: left;
 animation-delay: 4s;
}
 
 
.parent div {
 animation-name: animation_01;
 animation-duration:2s;
 animation-iteration-count:infinite;
 animation-fill-mode: forwards;
 opacity:0;
 }


@keyframes animation_01 {
  0% {
    opacity: 0
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 1
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
 <div class="content1">Here goes content1</div>
 <div class="content2">Here goes content2</div>
 <div class="content3">Here goes content3</div>
 <div class="content4">Here goes content4</div>
 <div class="content5">Here goes content5</div>
 </div>
```

As you can see in the code I display 5 contents on top of each other by using `keyframes` animation. I want to run this animation infinite therefore I put `animation-iteration-count:infinite;`.

However, once the animation reaches `content5` it does not go back to `content1` and starts all over again. Instead, it only goes back to `content4` and then shows/hides `content4` and `content5` in an infinite loop.

What do I have to change in my code so the animation goes back to `content1` and starts the animation all over again?

Comment: never make the delay a multiplier of the duration (or the opposite) ... if the duration is 2s and you delay one element by 4s and another one with 2s, then after 2 iteration they will start at the same time. Draw a timeline to better understand your issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define a longer animation.

The animation duration in this example is 5 seconds and the visible time frame is 2 seconds. Each div has a different delay, so when one is being fade out the other starts to fade in.

```css
.parent {
  height: 10%;
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}

.parent div {
  animation-name: animation_01;
  animation-duration: 5s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  opacity: 0;
}

.content1 {
  height: 100%;
  width: 20%;
  background-color: blue;
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 1;
}

.content2 {
  height: 100%;
  width: 20%;
  background-color: red;
  animation-delay: 1s;
  position: absolute;
}

.content3 {
  height: 100%;
  width: 20%;
  background-color: yellow;
  animation-delay: 2s;
  position: absolute;
}

.content4 {
  height: 100%;
  width: 20%;
  background-color: green;
  animation-delay: 3s;
  position: absolute;
}

.content5 {
  height: 100%;
  width: 20%;
  background-color: orange;
  animation-delay: 4s;
}

.parent {}

@keyframes animation_01 {
  20% {
    opacity: 1
  }
  0%, 40% , 100% {
    opacity: 0
  }
}


}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="content1">Here goes content1</div>
  <div class="content2">Here goes content2</div>
  <div class="content3">Here goes content3</div>
  <div class="content4">Here goes content4</div>
  <div class="content5">Here goes content5</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but how can I avoid the "blank" when content5 switches back to content1?

Comment: Instead of 6s for the whole animation set it to 5s.
Then, divide your 100% per 5 (as 5 items). Meaning that opacity goes to 1 from 0 to 20%, and get back to 0 from 20% to 40%

Comment: Fixed it, check it out

Comment: I am also wondering how exaclty the code works. So far my understanding was that within the keyframe animation it is defined how the frontend should look after the animation has reached X%. In the code above it seems that you define how the animation looks after each 20% and 40%. Do I understand this correctly?

Comment: Yes, also added an explanation to my answer.

Comment: Why is the visible time frime 2 seconds? As far as I can see in the animation it is 1 second.

Comment: Thanks guys. I also added another example with 8 items in the JSfiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/d0avt37f/12/